# Why does setting the derivatives of these two circle equations equal to each other have a solution that isn't on either circle?

Tags: calculus, circles, tangent-line

The circles are $x^2+ y^2 = 1$ and $(x-3)^2 + y^2 = 4$

It is given in the question that there is a line with a positive slope that is tangent to both circles. To attempt to solve for this I rearranged both equations so that $y$ was a function of $x$ and only considered the positive halves of the circles. After I took the derivative of both and set them equal to each other I found solutions $x=1$ and $-3$. How is $x=-3$ a solution? It's not on either circle. What does it mean for $x = -3$ to be a solution to this equation?

Comment: The derivative gives you the slope of the tangent line but the line can be anywhere on the plane. To fully describe a tangent line you need the to have $l$ in the equation $y = kx+l$ where $k$ is the slope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution technique is unlikely to work.  The points of intersection of the line with each circle should not both have the same $x$ coordinate.  (I'll say more about this at the end.)

But let's pretend that what we actually want to do is find one $x$ value (i.e., one vertical line on the Cartesian plane) where both circles have the same slope of the tangent (which is what you did).  We calculate
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \sqrt{1-x^2}
    &= \frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}  \text{ and }  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}
    &= \frac{3-x}{\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}}  
\end{align*}
These are the slopes for the upper halves of the circles.  We set these equal and solve.
\begin{align*}
\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} &= \frac{3-x}{\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}}  
\end{align*}
Amusingly, the only solution to this equation is $x = -3$.  The step we are about to take adds the [spurious solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) $x = 1$.  (This is an example of "extraneous solutions: multiplication", discussed at that page.)
\begin{align*}
(-x) \sqrt{4-(x-3)^2} &= (3-x) \sqrt{1-x^2}  \\
(-x)^2 (4-(x-3)^2) &= (3-x)^2(1-x^2)  \\
-5x^2 + 6x^3 - x^4 &= 9 - 6x -8x^2 +6x^3 -x^4  \\
3x^2 + 6x -9 &= 0  \\
3(x+3)(x-1) &= 0
\end{align*}
So we found two solutions.  Since in at least one step we multiplied through by an expresion that could be zero, we check all our solutions in the original equation.
$$  \frac{3}{\sqrt{-8}} = \frac{-(-3)}{\sqrt{1-(-3)^2}} \overset{?}{=}  \frac{3 - (-3)}{\sqrt{4-((-3)-3)^2}} = \frac{6}{\sqrt{-32}}  $$
Since $\sqrt{-32} = \sqrt{4 \cdot -8} = 2 \sqrt{-8}$, we find that the two sides are equal and $-3$ is a solution to the original equation.
$$  \frac{-1}{0} \unicode{x201C}\text{$=$"} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-1^2}} \overset{?}{=} \frac{3-1}{\sqrt{4-(1-3)^2}} \unicode{x201C}\text{$=$"} \frac{2}{0}  $$
I put quotes around those equal signs because equality is a property of values and none of these expressions have a value because division by zero is undefined.

What happened?  When $x = 1$, $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ of the two radicals we multiplied through by is zero, so we forced a spurious solution into our equation.

So, weirdly, the $x=-3$ is the correct solution.  What could it possibly mean?  Notice that at $x = -3$, the slope is complex valued.  There is a sensible way to interpret a circle as a cmoplex object.  So we could think of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ where now $x$ and $y$ are complex variables.  Unsurprisingly, it is hard to draw graphs of what is going on.  But if you could, you would see that the complex slope of the complex tangent line to these two complex circles is the same for the points on the circles with $x$-coordinate equal to $-3 + 0\mathrm{i}$.

---

So what is the right solution technique?

- First, don't throw away half of the circles.  Use implicit differentiation.  $2x_1 + 2y_1y_1' = 0$ and $2(x_2-3) + 2y_2y_2' = 0$ where we have used subscripts to keep track of which circle is which.
- It is not enough that the two slopes are equal.  For each tangent, $T$, to a point on one circle, there are two points on the other circle whose tangents are parallel to $T$.  We want a tangent line to one that is simultaneously a tangent line to the other.  That is "both" lines have the same slopes and same $y$-intercepts.

[image: two tangents on the other circle with the same slope]

Solving the first implicitly differentiated equation for its slope, we find
$$  y_1' = \frac{-x_1}{y_1}  $$
and so the point-slope form of a line tangent to the first circle is $y - y_1 = \frac{-x_1}{y_1}(x - x_1)$.  Solving for slope-intercept form, 
$$  y = \frac{-x_1}{y_1}x + \left( \frac{x_1^2}{y_1} +y_1 \right)  \text{.}  $$
Repeating for the other circle, 
$$  y_2' = \frac{3-x_2}{y_2}  \text{,}  $$
$y - y_2 = \frac{3-x_2}{y_2}(x - x_2)$ and so
$$ y = \frac{3-x_2}{y_2} x + \left( \frac{(x_2 - 3)x_2}{y_2} + y_2 \right)  \text{.}  $$

For these two lines to be the same line, they must have matching slopes and matching $y$-intercepts:  \begin{align*}
\frac{-x_1}{y_1} &= \frac{3-x_2}{y_2}  \\
\frac{x_1^2}{y_1} +y_1 &= \frac{(x_2 - 3)x_2}{y_2} + y_2
\end{align*}
Solve these with your two circle equations to find
$x_1 = -1/3$, $y_1 = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$, $x_2 = 7/3$, and $y_2 = \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}$.

---

I guess you are lucky there is a unique solution.  If the two circles did not have a point of tangency (at $(1,0)$), there could have been two doubly-tangent lines with positive slopes.

[image: two double tangents with positive slopes]

Comment: When I set the derivatives of each equation equal to one another, am I really only looking for an an x-value? In my mind, I imagine that for a tangent line to intersect both curves, it would have to be the same line, which means that it would have the same slope, which means that the derivatives would be equal. While I didn't expect all points that I received from setting the two equations equal to be on the line, I thought it was reasonable for a subset of these points to be on the line.

Comment: Why did I only receive lines instead of points? Also, thank you for your time.

Comment: @JorgeGomez : When you set the two upper-half-circle derivatives equal, all that was left was combinations of "$x$", so all you can find out is which choice(s) of $x$ make the two derivatives equal.  But two tangent lines having the same slope is *not enough* to make them the same line.  They also have to have the same $y$-intercept.  So to get **one line** tangent to both circles, we have to extract a matching pair of slope and a $y$-intercept.

Comment: @JorgeGomez : I say this in my answer, but again here: pick any point on one circle (except the left-most or right-most points).  There is a tangent line to that circle through that point.  That tangent line has a slope (unless you picked a left-most or right-most point, for which the slope is undefined).  There are *two* lines tangent to the other circle having the same slope.  Just matching slopes is far too loose to work.  (I'll add another image to my answer that might help.)

Answer (score 1):

The $x$ is the place where the tangent passes on the $x$ axis.
[image]

Comment: That's interesting, but at first glance it seems like it might be a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG the equation of any tangent of $x^2+y^2=1$

$$x\cos t+y\sin t=1$$

Now for tangency, the distance of the center from the tangent $=$ radius

$$2=\dfrac{|3\cos t-1|}{\sqrt{\cos^2t+\sin^2t}}$$

We need $\tan t>0$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your approach. But, I would love to; it seems like a very interesting take.

Comment: Please keep in mind that I'm only in my first year of undergrad.

Comment: @JorgeGomez, https://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00lone